# Amazon S3 bucket does not redirect folder URLs to index.html

Tags: amazon-s3, go, amazon-cloudfront

I have uploaded my HUGO static site into AWS S3 Bucket. I have also added the domain in cloudrfront.

The home index.html page works fine, but I cannot access my resources.
For example `https://www.example.com` works fine, but I cannot access `https://www.example.com/posts/`. I have to redirect links to the html file every time.

On localhost `https://www.example.com/posts/` displays automatically the page ( without redirecting `https://www.example.com/posts/` to `https://www.example.com/posts/index.html`.

Is there some property in cloudfront or Amazon S3 to replicate the behaviour of localhost and not have to change the links of the site?

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49082709/redirect-to-index-html-for-s3-subfolder) and let us know if it answers your question.

Answer (score 3):

CloudFront does not actually have this feature. You can redirect the root object `https://www.example.com/` to `https://www.example.com/index.html` by setting `DefaultRootObject`, but there's nothing for subdirectories such as `https://www.example.com/posts/`.

However, you can run arbitrary code on CloudFront using Lambda@Edge or CloudFront Functions, so it's possible for us to add this feature ourselves. With the "origin request" trigger we can rewrite the request to S3, changing `/posts/` to `/posts/index.html`. https://github.com/CloudUnder/lambda-edge-nice-urls has some good handling of paths that works well with Hugo. The Amazon documentation has an example of how you can do the same thing with [CloudFront Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/example-function-add-index.html).

Another option is to enable `uglyurls` in your config so that all links within you site have `index.html` hardcoded in to them.

Comment: It is a nice idea, but as @Alexandre stated above, this answer solved the problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49082709/redirect-to-index-html-for-s3-subfolder

Comment: this is really pain in the neck. a intuitive feature needs Lambda edge !?